# Ninject, заменить реализацию на другой класс

Tags: c#, binding, inversion-of-control, ninject

Знакомлюсь с IoC контейнерами и Ninject. По примерам в сети сделал реализацию для Ninject. Но как теперь мне выделить для объекта, скажем, не `YandexTranslator`, а `TestTranslator`? Создавать ещё один подобный конфиг-модуль, где будет уже `TestTranslator` вместо `YandexTranslator`, а после использовать этот конфиг для нового объекта `IKernel`?

Имеется ли более красивый способ подставлять другие классы с помощью Ninject?

```
class TranslatorConfigModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<ITranslatorType>().To<YandexTranslator>();
        Bind<IFilterInputText>().To<FilterLowerCase>();
    }
}
```

Создание объекта с помощью Ninject

```
IKernel ninjectKernel = new StandardKernel(new TranslatorConfigModule());
Translator translator = ninjectKernel.Get<Translator>();
```

Comment: Вы можете при регистрации указать имя того, что регистрируете, или вы можете использовать любой порождающий паттерн.

Comment: @i-one нет, внутри Translator имеется переменная интерфейса ITranslator. Сам Translator не наследуется от ITranslator

Comment: @i-one понадобился вместо YandexTranslator. Вот я и предположил `Bind<ITranslatorType>().To<TestTranslator>();`, но для этого я полагаю нужно вмешиваться в функцию Load и менять там

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужно подменить одну реализацию на другую, не затрагивая при этом существующий модуль, то есть два варианта.

Можно открепить абстракцию и прикрепить другую реализацию где-то сразу после инициализации ядра:

```
IKernel ninjectKernel = new StandardKernel(new TranslatorConfigModule());

ninjectKernel.Unbind<ITranslatorType>();
ninjectKernel.Bind<ITranslatorType>().To<TestTranslator>();

Translator translator = ninjectKernel.Get<Translator>();
```

Либо создать новый модуль, который наследует существующий и подменяет реализацию только для одной необходимой абстракции

```
class TestTranslatorConfigModule : TranslatorConfigModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        base.Load();
        Unbind<ITranslatorType>();
        Bind<ITranslatorType>().To<TestTranslator>();
    }
}
```

и, соответственно, использовать его *вместо* существующего при инициализации ядра

```
IKernel ninjectKernel = new StandardKernel(new TestTranslatorConfigModule());
```